# Need help: DataGridCheckBoxColumn two-way works only one-way

Tags: wpf, 2-way-object-databinding

I (..still learning wpf..) made a DataGrid with the first column showing that a signal is enabled or not.

In the xaml:

```
    <DataGrid.Columns> ...
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width ="30" Header="" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The ItemSouce of DataGrid is correctly set and bound with the data in list of `ObservableCollection<Signal> signalList`. Everything is correctly shown in DataGrid. So the binding from signalList to DataGrid here is working fine.

On the other side, I want that with every change of signalList, the DataGrid can update itself automatically. However, if I do

```
signalList[0].IsEnabled = true;
```

The DataGrid doesn't get updated. I searched a lot but still can't find the answer.

Did I miss something? Thx.

***Edit1:***

DataGrid do get updated, only if I click another row, and then draw the scroller out of sight. Then if I draw the scroller back, the row is correctly shown. I think I definitively missed something, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: Agree with aybe, probably need to implement it in your signalList.isenabled property

Comment: Your are right !! I add the interface and it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with help from Aybe and gavin. For record, I add my code here:

class Signal : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{
...
    private bool isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
      get { return isEnabled; }
      set { isEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEnabled"));}
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, e);
}
}
```